# Replacing inner keys from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Having the following array:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "233"
    [1]=>
    string(37) "some data"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "233"
    [1]=>
    string(68) "some other data"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "144"
    [1]=>
    string(38) "some other data"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "233"
    [1]=>
    string(42) "some other data"
  }
 }
```

I want to replace the values `233` and `144` (the key `0` from the inner array) by some random HEX color. The ones with the same keys (`233`) for example, has to have the same HEX color (`FFF000` for example in the desired solution above).

This is the function I use to generate random HEX colors:

```
function randHEXcolor() {
    return sprintf('%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}
```

My desired output should be:

```
 array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "FFF000"
    [1]=>
    string(37) "some data"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "FFF000"
    [1]=>
    string(68) "some other data"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "111333"
    [1]=>
    string(38) "some other data"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "FFF000"
    [1]=>
    string(42) "some other data"
  }
 }
```

How can I archieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you do: `foreach ($arr as &$subArr)` then you get a "reference" to the elements and you can change the desired values in the loop.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what errors you got if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
    if (!isset($temp[$item[0]]) {
        $temp[$item[0]] = randHEXcolor();
    }
    $item[0] = $temp[$item[0]];
}
```

Comment: As you can read on the post, the ones with the same keys (`233`) for example, has to have the same HEX color (`FFF000` for example in the desired solution above). This solution gives differents HEX color for the same keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all values to be translated to the same random color, you'll have to save those colors:

```
$colors_translation = array();

foreach ($array as &$item) {
  $color = $item[ 0 ];
  $translate = $colors_translation[ $color ];

  if (empty($translate)) {
    $colors_translations[ $color ] = $translate = randHEXcolor();
  }

  $item[ 0 ] = $translate;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Undefined index:  233` at the line `$translate = $colors_translation[ $color ];` .I dont know if it's because I'm using PHP 5.2 or not (I cant update the version as it's not my own machine)

Comment: Don't use `if empty` *after* you've already accessed the empty element.

Comment: its not your PHP version, its a setting about showing notices. @deceze is right - using `isset()` or `array_key_exists()` to check if the value exists

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `in_array` and `isset` functions:

```
$keys = [];
foreach ($arr as &$v) {  // $arr is your initial array
    if (in_array($v[0], ['233', '144'])) {
        if (!isset($keys[$v[0]])) $keys[$v[0]] = sprintf('%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
        $v[0] = $keys[$v[0]];
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65A4BB
            [1] => some data
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65A4BB
            [1] => some data
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DDB588
            [1] => some data
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65A4BB
            [1] => some data
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will create a color map as the array is traversed. Pre-populate `$colorMap` if you want pre-defined color translations.

```php
<?php

$array = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "233",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "233",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => "144",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
    3 => array(
        0 => "233",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
);

$colorMap = array();

foreach ($array as &$inner) {
    if (!array_key_exists($inner[0],$colorMap)) {
        $newColor = randHEXcolor();
        $colorMap[$inner[0]] = $newColor;
        $inner[0] = $newColor;
    } else {
        $inner[0] = $colorMap[$inner[0]];
    }
}

function randHEXcolor() {
    return sprintf('%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}

print_r($array);
print_r($colorMap);
```

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => F1519A
            [1] => some data
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => F1519A
            [1] => some data
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2F7D00
            [1] => some data
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => F1519A
            [1] => some data
        )

)

Array
(
    [233] => F1519A
    [144] => 2F7D00
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => "233",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => "233",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => "144",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
    3 => array(
        0 => "233",
        1 => "some data"
    ),
);
function randHEXcolor() {
    return sprintf('%06X', mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF));
}
$firstHex = randHEXcolor();
$secondHex = randHEXcolor();

foreach($array as $arrayIndex => &$arrayValue){
    if($arrayValue[0] == "144"){
        $arrayValue[0] = $firstHex;
    }
    if($arrayValue[0] == "233"){
        $arrayValue[0] = $secondHex;
    }
}
```

output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "AB8248"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "some data"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "AB8248"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "some data"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "22AF8B"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "some data"
  }
  [3]=>
  &array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "AB8248"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "some data"
  }
}
```